# Determining Whether a Family of Random Variables is Independent

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables with the same distribution and assume that $P\{X_i = X_j\} = 0$ for $i \neq j$. Determine whether the following collections of random variables are independent.

1. $\{R_i, \, 1 \leq i \leq n\}$, where $R_i = \sum_{j=1}^n {\bf 1}_{(X_j \leq X_i)}$
2. $\{Y_i, \, 1 \leq i \leq n\}$, where $Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^i {\bf 1}_{(X_j \leq X_i)}$

My understanding is that ${(X_j \leq X_i)} = \{\omega \in \Omega: X_j(\omega) \leq X_i(\omega)\}$ and that I need to determine whether $$P\{R_{i_{\ell}} \leq x_{i_{\ell}},\, 1 \leq \ell \leq k\} = \prod_{\ell = 1}^k P\{R_{i_{\ell}} \leq x_{i_{\ell}}\}$$ and $$P\{Y_{i_{\ell}} \leq x_{i_{\ell}},\, 1 \leq \ell \leq k\} = \prod_{\ell = 1}^k P\{Y_{i_{\ell}} \leq x_{i_{\ell}}\},$$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$. I must admit I don't even know where to start. I think I need to find some kind of relationship between the sets $(X_j \leq X_i)$ and $(X_j \leq x_i)$, but I'm not sure how to do that. A hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) is false and you can find a counter-example with $n=2$.